# Sort a vector of structs

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, struct

I have a vector of structs and I need help with how to sort them according to one of the values, and if those 2 values are the same, then sort it according to another parameter.

This is similar to other questions, but it has more to it.

What I am trying to implement is the scan line based polygon fill algorithm.

I build the active edge list, but then I need to sort it based on the x value in each struct object.  If the x values are the same, then they need to be sorted based on the inverse of the slopes for each struct object.

Here is the definition of the struct with the override operator < for normal sorting:

```
struct Bucket
{
    // Fields of a bucket list
    int ymax, x, dx, dy, sum;

    // Override the < operator, used for sorting based on the x value
    bool operator < (const Bucket& var) const
    {
        // Check if the x values are the same, if so
        // sort based on the ivnerse of the slope (dx/dy)
        /*if(x == var.x)
            return (dx/dy) < (var.dx/var.dy);
        else*/
            return (x < var.x);
    }
};
```

I commented out the if then else statement because it does compile, but causes a floating point error and the program crashes.
The exact error is: "Floating point exception (core dumped)"

I also tried casting each division to (int) but that did not work either.

My question: Is there a way to do the sort similar to the way I have it, or should I write my own sort method.

If I should make my own sort method, please provide a link or something to a simple method which can help.

Thanks

Comment: These are int values, and as such will perform integer division. Thus casting to ints will not do much good (or anything for that matter). was the original code all floats/doubles? (and if so, can you throw that in the question instead?)

Comment: @WhozCraig - No, all the values are ints from the struct. This is all code I am writing.

Comment: @AK4749 pretty sure he is using stl's sort,and the default std::less<> functor will work fine so long as his operator <() is defined correctly.

Comment: @Sergey - That was my mistake when typing it in. I fixed the typo.

Comment: There is no test for dy == 0, so the floating point exception is a divide by 0.

Comment: @RXC all the ones used in the expressions in this sample *are* ints, and thus, again, will be integer division, so I'm still struggling to see where the floating point exception will come from.

Comment: @WhozCraig - The parenthesis thing was a typo, but it does compile with the parenthesis in their and I get the floating point error. I have no idea why I get a floating point error, but I do. I am using Ubuntu and g++.

Comment: i've seen plenty of div-0 exceptions, but never reported as a float exception when all the operands are ints. learn something new everyday I guess. he should definitely check for (0) in both denominators regardless. near-topic: is a div-zero exception intrinsic to the architecture? Ie. can it report as a float-exception on one architecture, and an int-div-by-zero on another?

Comment: The floating-point exception is implementation-dependent.  For some architectures conversion between int and float isn't expensive, and hardware floating-point division is much faster than software-based integer division.  So it is cheaper to convert to float, use float division, and convert the result to back integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should implement double division, because with integers, when you have for example 5/6 it results in 0, and division by 0 is not possible as we know. That's why the program crashes.
SO change the members of the structure to doubles.And then you should take care of some precision issues but at least the program won't crash assuming that you are not allowing 0 value for dy.

Comment: I changed my dx and dy variables to ints and it compiles and runs. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **tuple** which overrides different operators for lexicographic comparisons (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/operator_cmp)

```
typedef std::tuple<int, int, int, int, int> Bucket;
```

But it's a bit annoying to change your struct to a tuple. You can use **tie** that will make the tuple for you.

```
bool operator < (const Bucket& var) const
{
    std::tie(x, dx/dy) < std::tie(var.x, var.dx/var.dy);
}
```

However, this solution **won't compile** because it works with references.

```
bool operator < (const Bucket& var) const
{
    int slope = dx/dy;
    int var_slope = var.dx/var.dy;  
    std::tie(x, slope) < std::tie(var.x, var_slope);
}
```

It's not the most efficient solution, but readability is quite good.
Of course, you still have the division by 0 in this example.